# Chrome Extension Content Script with Pagination

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have written a simple Chrome extension with a content script which will detect when you have done a search in LinkedIn, and add a button to each person in the list, so you can do something with them.

It all works fine when you first press search, and the buttons are added. But the problem is with the pagination. Every time I click on the next page number, the content script continues to append the button to the same first 10 people in the result, even though they are not visible now. So the content-script seems to fire before whatever paginates the results decides what to draw on the page.

Has anyone had similar problems with trying to inject HTML into a paginated list using a Chrome extension, and is there a way to get around it?

Comment: The problem is definitely in your code, show it in the question along with manifest.json.

Comment: also likely very specific to that webpage. spent more time debugging this. you can look at the dom, your selectors and see why is picking the wrong ones.

Comment: The problem is related to whatever pagination mechanism is used on  LinkedIn. I have found that if I scrape the LinkedIn dom from the popup via a message to a content script, it captures the current list of people. If I try to do the same thing when the content script itself loads, it always captures the first 10 contacts regardless of page selected. I think it might be because the content script fires before LinkedIn's scripts update the list of contacts on the screen.  I was hoping someone else might have developed a LinkedIn plug in , and might have a workaround

Comment: In that case, shouldn't it always capture the previous 10, not the first 10?  I'm guessing the problem would be that LinkedIn is using AJAX to load the people, which your extension isn't catching.  If so, I think there are a few SO questions about that (possibly dealing with Youtube, but the ideas may stay the same).

Comment: Thanks Teepeemm. I think it is something like how you describe. I've found some  SO questions about AJAX, and I've tried a few things but I can't get a solution yet. I will keep trying and post back here if I find a good way to handle Linked In.